# Button Click Save in KO

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a ko maaaped array like this.

```
 var Type = [];          
        Type.push("Flip");
        Type.push("Bar");
        Type.push("Foo");

        // converting the json to ko mapped collection
        viewModel = {
            firstValue: ko.observable("hello"),
            Type: ko.mapping.fromJS(Type),
            save: function () {
                alert(viewModel.Type[0]);
                alert("have to save the values here");
            },

        };
```

I used foreach to create a input to edit that array.

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: Type">
<p><input data-bind='value: $parent.Type()[$index()]' /></p>
```

```
 <button data-bind='click: save'> Save </button>
```

i want to save the edited value back to array in button click,, instead of saving that instantlly. how to achieve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/mS6LF/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your inputs to a temporary copy instead of the actual data, then on save you copy the temp data to the the actual values.

Here's and updated fiddle showing that approach: http://jsfiddle.net/mS6LF/8/

```
var Type = [];
Type.push({ value: "Flip", temp: "Flip"});
Type.push({ value: "Bar", temp: "Bar"});
Type.push({ value: "Foo", temp: "Foo"});

// converting the json to ko mapped collection
viewModel = {
    firstValue: ko.observable("hello"),
    Type: ko.mapping.fromJS(Type),
    save: function () {        
        // Loop through array and set all temp values to the actual value.
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Type(), function(element){
            element.value(element.temp());
        });
    },

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The array now holds objects with the actual value and a copy. We bind the input to the copy instead of the actual data.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Type">
    <p>
        <input data-bind='value: temp' />
        Actual = <span data-bind='text: value'></span>
    </p>
</div>
<button data-bind='click: save'>Save</button>
```

---

For a more sophisticated approach, [see Ryan Niemeyer's `protectedObservable` blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html).

Comment: good answer.. i have updated your example based on the wonderful article you mentioned. kindly check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I updated [geoff-appleford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7793/geoff-appleford) example with modification based on [Ryan Niemeyer's `protectedObservable`](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) provided in the previous answer

There is no need to add or duplicate each value in your array with `original-value` and `temp-value`. You just need to make sure that your observable items are kind of `protectedObservable`
kindly check my example **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/mS6LF/10/)**.